# Herkunft Aussprache Ordinalzahlen 4 "Virrtä" und 7 "Sippte" im Rheinland/Süddeutschland

Tags: pronunciation, history, numbers

Verfolgt man bspw. die öffentlich-rechtlichen Medien (wie den DLF, vornehmlich im Rheinland produziert), gibt es offenbar insbesondere im rheinländischen und südlichen Teil Deutschlands die verbreiteten Varianten der Aussprache:

- *Virrtä* (ungefähr [ˈfɪʁtɐ]) oder *Virrdä* (ungefähr [ˈfɪʁdɛː]) statt *Vierte* [ˈfiːɐ̯tə] für die Ordinalzahl 4 und
- *Sippte* statt der ohnehin schon verkürzten Form *Siebte* von *Siebente* für die Ordinalzahl 7.

Gibt es Forschung zur Herkunft der abweichende Aussprache der Ordinalzahlen 4 und 7?

Comment: Was genau ist anders? Erster Vokal ist kürzer? Oder was genau ist gemeint? Ich sehe keinen großen Unterschied zwischen *sippte* (vermutete Aussprache [ˈzɪptə]) und *siebte* ([ˈziːptə]), von der Vokallänge mal abgesehen. Da ist das bayrische *siemte* ([ˈsiːmtə]) schon deutlich weiter vom Standard entfernt (anstelle des stimmhaften [z] ein stimmloses [s], und aus dem Verschlusslaut [p] wird ein sonores und nasales [m]).

Comment: Mit IPA-Halbwissen, sieben [ˈziːbn̩] > siebente [ˈziːbn̩tə], abgekürzt siebte [ˈziːbtə]. Andere Variante klingt in meinen Ohren eher wie suppte [ˈzʊptə] mit einem [ɪp] statt [ʊp]. Wenn man z. B. zur "Hundertsippten" Ausgabe eines Magazins begrüßt. Die Frage sollte aber keinen pejorativen Character haben, sondern ist einfach interessehalber.

Comment: Du schreibst "abweichende Aussprache". Es wäre gut, wenn du zur Klärung (in der Frage) noch die von dir in diesem Zusammenhang als "normal" angesehene Aussprache beschreibst. Damit wäre noch klarer und eindeutiger, worum es geht.

Comment: Ich habe den Tag _etymology_ entfernt, weil er in meinen Augen hier nicht einschlägig ist. _Etymologie_ bezeichnet die Geschichte der Worte bzw. die Erforschung der Wortherkunft, hier geht es in meinen Augen um einen anderen Aspekt der Sprachgeschichte. Ich habe außerdem den Tag _pronunciation_ hinzugefügt, weil er mir hier passend erscheint.

Comment: Zu der Frage würde ein Hörbeispiel passen, um die "alternative" Aussprache darzulegen und vor allem, damit alle über dasselbe sprechen, bzw wissen, was gemeint ist. Evtl aus der Mediathek des erwähnten DLF.

Comment: Ich sehe hier eigentlich keine entscheidende Veränderung der Aussprache, außer (ganz vielleicht, das fällt für mich unter 'lokale Variation') das Ausmaß der Dehnung (oder Kürzung) der Vokalgruppen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Kürzung vor Konsonant im Silbenauslaut

Bei einer Aussprache wie /ˈfɪrtər/ mit kurzem /ɪ/ an Stelle von /ˈfiːrtər/ mit langem /iː/ handelt es sich vermutlich um eine Kürzung vor Konsonanten im Silbenauslaut.

Dasselbe Phänomen lässt sich in Wörtern wie *gedacht, Nachbar, (Grill-)Rost, Hochzeit, gibt, ging, fing, hing* beobachten. In allen diesen Wörtern folgt auf den (ursprünglich) langen Vokal ein odere mehrere Konsonanten im Silbenauslaut.

Linguistisch lässt sich das Phänomen erklären mit den [Moren](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mora_(Einheit)), einer Einheit für die Dauer von Silben. In diesem Fall ist anzunehmen, dass ein kurzer Vokal eine More zählt, ein langer Vokal zwei Moren, und Konsonanten im Silbenauslaut ebenfalls eine More. Ein Wort wie *(Grill-)Rost* mit langem /oː/ hätte also drei Moren, zwei wegen dem langen Vokal und eine dritte durch die Konsonanten im Silbenauslaut:

```
Aussprache: /roː  st/
              |    |
             / \   |
Moren:       1  1  1
             \  |  /
              \ | /
                |
Silben:         1
```

Bestimmte Dialekte bevorzugen Silben mit zwei Moren. Sie kürzen den langen Vokal in dreimorigen Silben, um die bevorzugte Zweimorigkeit herzustellen:

```
Aussprache: /rɔ st/
              |  |
Moren:        1  1
              \ /
               |
Silben:        1
```

Bei *Vierter* geschieht etwas Ähnliches: Bei einer Aussprache mit langem /iː/ entsteht eine dreimorige Silbe:

```
Aussprache: /fiː  rt əl/
              |   |   |
             / \  |   |
Moren:       1 1  1   1
             \ | /    |
               |      |
Silben:        1      1
```

Durch die Kürzung des /iː/ zu einem /ɪ/ wird die bevorzugte Zweimorigkeit hergestellt:

```
Aussprache: /fɪ rt əl/
              | |   |
Moren:        1 1   1
              \ /   |
               |    |
Silben:        1    1
```

Solche Kürzungen sind meines Wissens speziell im mitteldeutschen Raum verbreitet, wozu auch die rheinischen Dialekte gehören.

Die Verhältnisse sind allerdings nicht in allen Dialekten gleich. Einige Dialekte haben kein Problem mit dreimorigen Silben und führen keine solchen Kürzungen durch. Auch gelten nicht überall dieselben Regeln für die Moren von Konsonanten im Auslaut. In vielen Dialekten haben einfache Konsonanten im Auslaut keine More, so dass die Aussprache von Wörtern wie *Bad* mit langem Vokal nicht gegen die Zweimorigkeit verstösst. Andererseits gibt es auch Dialekte, wo nicht einmal Konsonantencluster im Auslaut eine More haben, so dass auch in Wörtern wie *Nacht* der Vokal gedehnt wird, um die bevorzugte Zweimorigkeit zu erreichen.

### Ausgebliebene Dehnung vor Konsonant im Silbenauslaut?

Etymologisch gesehen hat das lange /iː/ im Wort *sieben* einen anderen Ursprung als im Wort *vier.* Das /iː/ in *sieben* geht auf ein kurzes /ɪ/ zurück, das im Rahmen der Dehnung in offener Tonsilbe zu einem langen /iː/ gedehnt worden ist. Das /iː/ in *vier* geht hingegen auf einen Diphthong /iə/ zurück, der im Rahmen der neuhochdeutschen Monophthongierung zu einem langen /iː/ monophthongiert worden ist.

Beim Wort *siebte* sind also zwei verschiedene Erklärungen für eine Aussprache mit kurzem /ɪ/ denkbar:

1. Zuerst ist das ursprünglich kurze /ɪ/ zu einem langen /iː/ gedehnt worden. Danach ist der lange Vokal wegen Bevorzugung der Zweimorigkeit gekürzt worden. Somit hätten wir hier ebenfalls eine Kürzung vor Konsonant im Silbenauslaut – genau gleich wie bei *(Grill-)Rost* oder *Vierter.*
2. Eine Dehnung des kurzen /ɪ/ zu einem langen /iː/ hat gar nie stattgefunden, da keine offene Tonsilbe vorliegt. Das Wort hat die ursprüngliche Aussprache mit kurzem /ɪ/ behalten.

Ich kann nicht beurteilen, welcher dieser beiden Fälle bei der Aussprache von *siebte* mit kurzem /ɪ/ vorliegt.